# jquery find out what would have fired without stopPropagation

Tags: jquery, events, checkbox

I have found an issue in some of my html, a checkbox is getting it's default event blocked.  Very annoying.  I found that if I add a stopPropagation directly to the checkbox that it works.  I'd like to know if there's a way to find out what event is being fired rather than just stopping the propagation (I don't like having events work in ways that i don't expect them to :)).

Is it possible to set something like that up?

Comment: Are you checking the element if something is clicked? Are you reinventing a label element?

Comment: have you tried firebug/chrome developer tools?

Comment: epascarello - i'm not trying to do anything to the check box, but when i click it nothing happens, it wasn't until I attach an event that stops propagation that it starts to work again.  that's the whole problem.

Answer (score 1):

Install firebug, create a breakpoint in the event handler of the checkbox and debug. That's all.

Comment: i'm using chrome but this seems like it should do the trick.  Not sure why i didn't think of it :).  tnx

Comment: wierd, running it through the only event attached to my element is the one i added to stop Propagation.  lame.

Answer (score 1):

You should get [Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2) set up in your brower(s).

Fire it up and it shows you all the events that are bound to the various elements on the page. I use it all the time.

Comment: this looks pretty cool, but the css on my page seems to not show the part i care about :).  But i'll keep it in my bookmark for later.  Thanks.

Comment: no problem! In that case, I just use firebug or chrome dev tools to change the css on the part you care about. It will depend on your circumstances, but do what you need to do to get it on the page and then run visual event to see what is going on